# Change router ip address?

Tags: ip

I got banned from a webstore for hitting refresh too many times. It banned  my ip. I want to change my ip now inorder to access the site again.If i spook my ip will it force the isp to change the router ip? I want to change my modems/routers ip.  Thank you

Comment: It won't just change you need to ask your isp

Comment: What kind of online store bans someone from mashing the refresh button?!?! I have done that tons of places and never had an issue... or did you have some automated thing doing dozens of refreshes per second?

Comment: This might be illegal in the United States. Arguably, by banning you, the webstore has revoked your permission to access it, thus rendering your attempt to access it intentionally exceeding your authorized access, which is a crime under the Computer Fraud and Abuse Act. I would just wait for the IP ban to expire or email the administrator of the webstore and ask them to lift the ban.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just change your public IP address, it is assigned to you by your ISP either statically or via a DHCP pool of addresses.

If your public IP address is statically assigned, only your ISP can change it manually. Note that sometimes if you get DHCP you MAY still have a static assignment.

If you are fairly certain you get your public IP address dynamically from your ISP, log into your router and see what the DHCP Lease time is or see when your DHCP lease expires, it varies by router... Disconnect your router near the expiration time and wait until after the timer has expired, the longer the better, then reconnect the router so it gets a new DHCP address. The idea is to so your IP address will be reused and given out to another user so you are forced to get another one. How long this will take will vary based on how busy your ISP is, it might take seconds, hours, or days, but it is typically less than a full day. Other than that, a decent DHCP server will give you back the same address every time unless it has been reused.